# How to arrange nodes of graph with top N (eg. top 5) major component above and small component below in a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am using networkx to visualize a graph, I want to draw something like the attached figure. All the small connected components are align below the major components, anyone know how to do it with networkx or other python package? Thanks a lot[image]

Comment: I have to admit I have severe problems understanding this figure. In any case, I think this question is rather off-topic here and might be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com